# How to accelerate mempool data access with bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, mempool

What could I do to accelerate access to the data I get when I call for example: bitcoin-cli getblocktemplate ?

If I would like to be able to be the fisrt one who get information about all the new tx getting into the mempool in term of milliseconds is there any optimization to bitcoin.conf or hardware or node deployment or even modification to code that I could do to be the first one to get the info?

All I want to be able to do with my bitcoind would be see the mempool info coming in as fast as possible (and if possible mining). So I'm wondering if I can remove any other feature to get this faster?

Thanks in advance for any clue!

Comment: I want make some consideration. First all, the word "all" in the Bitcoin network is a lie, because your node can work on a wrong chain and make a not util work. Second, all node inside the mempool doesn't has the same transaction in the same moment, for this reason different chain of block during the verification can contain different transaction. In conclusion, I don't know the answer at your question, I think that if this procedure is possible through bitcoin.conf, all node can use this conf and it doesn't is the pawerfool config because all node can have this conf.

Comment: Sometimes the .conf help to leverage all the server's power (cpu, ram, etc) not everyone need to get the mempool faster so maybe not every bitcoind user is willing to invest money in powerful hardware and time tweaking its .conf to get the most of his hardware investment. And yes I was aware that every node has a sligthly different mempool but I want to know how I can get the information I can get in my mempool the fastest possible way.

Comment: I agree with you, I added only some consideration and I'm sure that is there is an answer to your question some people can help you.